# Como analisar a entrada na condição do while?

Tags: c, input, while, scanf

Eu estou aprendendo C, e como a linguagem em que eu fui "alfabetizado" é Python, eu costumo fazer associações para assimilar melhor.

Em Python, eu posso receber um valor direto na condição do while.
Ex.:

```
while int(input()) != 0:
    faça isso
```

É possível também (em Python e em C) declarar uma variáve antes do while, receber um novo valor no fim de cada laço e então analisar.
Ex (em Python).:

```
n = 1
while n != 0:
    faça isso

    n = int(input)
```

Mas eu queria saber se tem alguma forma de fazer como no primeiro exemplo, porém em C.

Eu tentei da seguinte forma (em C):

```
int n;

while(scanf("%d", &n) != 0){
    faça isso
}
```

Mas ele executa o laço mesmo que eu digite 0.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Já tentou `while(scanf("%d", &n) && n != 0)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você executa `scanf("%d", &n)` ele ira armazenar o valor lido no endereço `n`. Logo basta adicionar `&& n != 0` para analisar a entrada.

```
int n;
while(scanf("%d", &n) && n != 0){
  printf("Não é zero! :)\n");
}
printf("Ops :(\n");
```

> Exemplo funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/IdenticalLustrousTurtle).

Comment: O `scanf` retorna a quantidade de variáveis lidas, então caso se alcance o final da entrada ele sairá do laço. Abordagem interessante

Comment: Muito obrigado. Era exatamente isso que eu tava procurando. Valeu!

Answer (score 0):

Basta adicionar o "&&" entre `scanf("%d", &n)` e o `n != 0` para que o compilador analise as duas condições.
Ficando da seguinte forma:

```
int n;

while(scanf("%d", &n) && n != 0) {
  faca tal coisa;
}
```